# How to sum measures per group in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here's the edited version:

I have this sample table using powerbi where %Currnt is a measure and the rest is column. I also have filters where i just selected area=asia and salesoffice=australia and fyear =2018. I have to sum up %currnt column(measure) and place it under ExpectedResult column.

But as you can see in my current resultset, when i sum the %Current seems like its it returns its average (0.485) rather than the sum (0.97). I need to get the sum of the %currnt first. My expected result is 0.97 per row

Does anyone of you encounter the same problem? Let me know if you find any solution. Appreciate your help. Thanks

```
FYear   FMonth        CurrentAR    TotalAR    CountFY   %Currnt    ExpectedResult**  

 2018    August, 2018  18,000.00   25,000.00     2         0.72       0.97   
 2018    July, 2018    33,000.00   130,000.00    2         0.25       0.97
                                                         **0.485**
```

Comment: Post a data sample along with the expected and actual results. Otherwise nobody will be able to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I have understand your problem, but you have to consider that, in DAX, when creating a measure, the context of the query is everything.

I mean that if you create a measure to count or calculate something, DAX apply it the current context of the data, ie if you apply filters, these filter is applied to the context. So maybe, you should consider create measure that is context free for the calculation of the MAX CountFY column using CALCULATION DAX formula.

Let me know if this helps. If you want to go further can you post and sample data to investigate deeper on your problem?

Comment: can you help me on how to create DAX formula to get my expected results.